# Related tag list in Top Users for tag contains tag itself

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, related-tags

On the [tag info page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/topusers), no matter which one of the subtabs (user, hot, new or synonyms) is selected, the list of related tags contains a tag itself:

> [image: this is a bug!]

To see this, click "top users" in the tag hover infobox or "more »" in the tag info page under Top Answerers. All subtabs are affected.

Comment: @Cai dup says that it's relevant only for "Top Users". In my case - for all subtabs.

Comment: Hmm, true – it's the same issue though, if anything the dupe should be updated to say it is all tabs. It does seem to be limited to those [`/tags/$tag/$tab`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/topusers) pages though (i.e. it doesn't happen on [`/questions/tagged/$tag`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) pages, and interestingly [`/tags/$tag/`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/)).