# The count of the related tags are not the same as questions tagged count in top users page

Tags: bug, top-users, related-tags

When reading this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290178), I noticed an another issue.

The count of the **related tags** are not the same as **questions tagged** count.

- [**feature-request** top users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/topusers)

> [image: feature-request top users page]

- [**status-completed** top users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-completed/topusers)

> [image: status-completed top users page]

Comment: [tag:status-bydesign], caching?

Comment: Isn't repeating that same tag under the *related tags* heading the real bug?